# can i duplicate a Tab item based on a number in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Im new to asp.net core and im working on a project where I have to create a page where I have to create to duplicate Tab page based on a number.
user enters number in the textbox and based on the number tab items have to be created which carries the same form elements.
I tried with creating tab page but unable to continue the next step,
please help me with this.
thanks in advance

i have created a partial view in the following code
This is the model I pass to my view as list:

```
public class DbContent : ContentPage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public bool Gender{ get; set; }

    public string treatment{ get; set; }
    public List<string> treatmentlist{ get; set; }
}
```

in the cshtml i have called my models and tried to create tab based on the treatmentlist

```
<div class="example">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    foreach (var merit in item.treatmentlist)
                                 {
                                     <li>@treatmentlist</li>
                                 }
</ul>
</div>
```

uptill here I tried to create dynamic tab page but after this I have to add the controls similar to all the tab pages.

I have stopped here,
can somebody please help me on how to copy the controls which are placed in tab1 to all the tabs , like creating a dulicate or clone the controls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain in detail what is the Tab page, also show us the codes and problems what you have now.

Comment: sure, these are the below points

Comment: 1.added a partial view with the following code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provide is still not complete to reproduce your problem.

I made an example based on my understanding, you may take a look the below codes:

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">TabNumber:</label>
            <input id="tabNumber" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="addTab" class="btn btn-primary">Add Tab</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="tab-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Tab1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_FormPartial")
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#addTab").on("click", function () {
            var count = $("#myTab li").length;
            var tabnumber = $("#tabNumber").val();
            for (var i = 0; i < tabnumber; i++) {
                count++;
                var newTab = "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' id ='tab-" + count + "' data-toggle='tab' href ='#tab" + count + "' role ='tab' aria-selected='false'>Tab" + count + "</a ></li >"
                $("#myTab").append(newTab);
                var newTabContent = "<div class='tab-pane fade' id='tab" + count + "' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='tab-" + count + "'></div>"
                $("#myTabContent").append(newTabContent);
                loadContent(count)
            }
        })

        function loadContent(i) {
            var count = i;
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/Tab/GetNewTab',
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#tab" + count).append(res);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**_FormPartial.cshtml(partial view):**

```
@model User

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Age" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]